# Oauth implementation in netsuite using php

Tags: php, oauth, netsuite

I have tried to access Netsuite by account id, username and password using PHP Toolkit. And I can get customer details using the above credentials. i have access token. But Now I tried to access Netsuite using the access token. I need PHP code to access Netsuite using token and I want to get customer details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is way too broad, please post code that you have used, what issues/errors you're getting, etc.

Comment: i have code to access Netsuite using credentials not using Oauth. i need that code using Oauth only.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is some code I wrote for a PHP -> NS integration using Restlets and OAuth:

```
define("NETSUITE_URL", 'https://rest.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl');
define("NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_ACCOUNT", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET", 'XXXXXX');

function sendOrderToNS($details) {
    $data_string = json_encode($details);
    
    $oauth_nonce = md5(mt_rand());
    $oauth_timestamp = time();
    $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256';
    $oauth_version = "1.0";
            
    $base_string =
        "POST&" . urlencode(NETSUITE_URL) . "&" .
        urlencode(
            "deploy=" . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID
          . "&oauth_consumer_key=" . NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY
          . "&oauth_nonce=" . $oauth_nonce
          . "&oauth_signature_method=" . $oauth_signature_method
          . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $oauth_timestamp
          . "&oauth_token=" . NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID
          . "&oauth_version=" . $oauth_version
          . "&realm=" . NETSUITE_ACCOUNT
          . "&script=" . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID
        );
    $sig_string = urlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET) . '&' . urlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $base_string, $sig_string, true));
    
    $auth_header = "OAuth "
        . 'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '", '
        . 'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($oauth_version) . '", '
        . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($oauth_nonce) . '", '
        . 'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($oauth_signature_method) . '", '
        . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY) . '", '
        . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID) . '", '  
        . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp) . '", '
        . 'realm="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_ACCOUNT) .'"';
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, NETSUITE_URL . '?&script=' . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID . '&deploy=' . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID . '&realm=' . NETSUITE_ACCOUNT);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Authorization: ' . $auth_header,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
    ]);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer is help to proceed the next step. I tried your code for getting customer details using Netsuite script. But I get an empty response from OAuth. 
In this way, we need to create a script for each and every independent Netsuite account. Is there any possible way to get customer details without creating scripts in Netsuite accounts?

Comment: Thanks lot michoel. Your code is working properly. I have made mistakes on passing data. I sent data as a string wrongly. I have added these 2 lines only. $datastring = array('recordtype' => 'customer', 'id' => '5');
sendOrderToNS($datastring);

Comment: Is there any possible way to get customer details without creating scripts in Netsuite accounts?

Comment: Great example, thank you. Do not forget to `curl_close($ch);`.

Comment: Important to note to those new to TBA. The oder of the $auth_header is SUPER important. `The OAuth spec says to sort lexigraphically, which is the default alphabetical sort for many libraries.`

Comment: How about GET methods? For example, getting a client info

Comment: anybody knows how to do in c#
I am using Restlet with C# with TBA Oauth 1.0 and OAuthBase.cs whenever I append a special character with query string its get messed and return as INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT have a look at below string

restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=198&deploy=1&columns=internalid,itemid&type=item&filters=matrix;is;F

Answer (score 3):

I'd comment but am not able to yet. michoel's answer is correct but threw "invalid login attempt" errors when 'realm=...' was part of the $auth_header var. Taking that string out removed the issue.

Comment: Same here. The OAuth spec says to not include `realm`.  I had to remove it to get it work work (in my case in Delphi instead of PHP).

Comment: @Brian What did you do with GET requests?

Answer (score 3):

Netsuite TBA Restlets won't support SHA1 anymore in 2021.1 release , you have to change PHP code to
from $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';  to $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256';
and
from $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base_string, $sig_string, true)); to $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $base_string, $sig_string, true));

```
define("NETSUITE_URL", 'https://rest.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl');
define("NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_ACCOUNT", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET", 'XXXXXX');

function sendOrderToNS($details) {
    $data_string = json_encode($details);

    $oauth_nonce = md5(mt_rand());
    $oauth_timestamp = time();
    $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256';
    $oauth_version = "1.0";

    $base_string =
        "POST&" . urlencode(NETSUITE_URL) . "&" .
        urlencode(
            "deploy=" . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID
          . "&oauth_consumer_key=" . NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY
          . "&oauth_nonce=" . $oauth_nonce
          . "&oauth_signature_method=" . $oauth_signature_method
          . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $oauth_timestamp
          . "&oauth_token=" . NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID
          . "&oauth_version=" . $oauth_version
          . "&realm=" . NETSUITE_ACCOUNT
          . "&script=" . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID
        );
    $sig_string = urlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET) . '&' . urlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $base_string, $sig_string, true));

    $auth_header = "OAuth "
        . 'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '", '
        . 'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($oauth_version) . '", '
        . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($oauth_nonce) . '", '
        . 'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($oauth_signature_method) . '", '
        . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY) . '", '
        . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID) . '", '  
        . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp) . '", '
        . 'realm="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_ACCOUNT) .'"';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, NETSUITE_URL . '?&script=' . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID . '&deploy=' . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID . '&realm=' . NETSUITE_ACCOUNT);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Authorization: ' . $auth_header,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
    ]);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Does anyone were able to work this out on GET request? I'm stuck with INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT error I'm using Phils revised code but simply use GET instead of POST.