# Netsuite Oauth Through consumer key and Secret

Tags: netsuite

Referring to Stack solution
[Oauth implementation in netsuite using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867476/oauth-implementation-in-netsuite-using-php/32983952#32983952)

What we have to send in $details?

Answer (score 0):

Your data object. It should be a JSON formatted object.