# Netsuite Oauth 1.0 authentication from swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, netsuite, restlet, oauth-1.0a

I am trying to integrate netsuite modules in iOS application. I am not able generate proper oauth signature for the header. I have tried using 'OAuthSwift' library for this purpose, but I have no proper idea on how to add the headers like oauth_nonce, oauth_signature. I have searched many websites and checked stackoverflow references  but found none for my requirement.

As per the comment I followed the java code posted [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51286409/netsuite-token-based-authentication].

Here is the code I have worked on. The response I got is INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT. My guess is, maybe the OAUTH_Signature is wrong. Please help me.

```
 import UIKit
 import CommonCrypto

 class ViewController: UIViewController {


var OAuth = "";
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

   var oauth_val = mediate();
    
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=xxx&deploy=x")
    guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
    // Create URL Request
    var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
    // Specify HTTP Method to use
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    
    //http header
    
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue(oauth_val, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    // Send HTTP Request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        
        // Check if Error took place
        if let error = error {
            print("Error took place \(error)")
            return
        }
        
        // Read HTTP Response Status code
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Response HTTP Status code: \(response.statusCode)")
        }
        
        // Convert HTTP Response Data to a simple String
        if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
        }
        
    }
    task.resume()
   }
func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
  let letters = "2312312312312sadadadadNKSNSKMSLMXSX"
  return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}


func computeSignature(baseString: String, keyString: String) -> String
{
    let hmacResult:String = keyString.hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm.SHA1, key: keyString)
    return hmacResult
}


func mediate()-> String
{
    let base_url =  "https://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?"
    let http_method =  "GET"
    var token_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    var token_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    var consumerkey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    var consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    var SIGNATURE_METHOD = "HMAC-SHA1"
    var OAUTH_NONCE = randomString(length: 20)
    var TIME_STAMP = String(Date().toMillis())
    var OAUTH_VERSION = "1.0"
    var SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_ID = "xxx"
    var SCRIPT_ID = "xxx"
    var REALM = "xxxxx"
        
    var encdata = ""
    encdata = encdata + "deploy=" + SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_ID + "&"
    encdata = encdata + "oauth_consumer_key=" + consumerkey + "&"
    encdata = encdata + "oauth_nonce=" + OAUTH_NONCE + "&"
    encdata = encdata + "oauth_signature_method=" + SIGNATURE_METHOD + "&"
    encdata = encdata + "oauth_timestamp=" + TIME_STAMP + "&"
    encdata = encdata + "oauth_token=" + token_id + "&"
    encdata = encdata + "oauth_version=" + OAUTH_VERSION + "&"
    encdata = encdata + "script=" + SCRIPT_ID
        
    let encodeData = encdata.urlEncoded()!
    
    let completeData = http_method + "&"  + base_url.urlEncoded()! + "&" + encodeData
    
    var key = "";
    
    key = consumer_secret.urlEncoded()! + "&" + token_secret.urlEncoded()!
    
    var signature = computeSignature(baseString: completeData, keyString: key)

                OAuth = "OAuth realm=\"" + REALM + "\",";
                OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + consumerkey + "\",";
                OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_token=\"" + token_id + "\",";
                OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",";
                OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_timestamp=\"" + TIME_STAMP + "\",";
                OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_nonce=\"" + OAUTH_NONCE + "\",";
                OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_version=\"" + "1.0" + "\",";
                OAuth = OAuth + "oauth_signature=\"" + signature + "\"";
                return OAuth;
}



func printCharactersInSet(set: NSCharacterSet) {
    var characters = ""
    let iSet = set.inverted
    for i: UInt32 in 32..<127 {
        let c = Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(i))!)
        if iSet.hasMember(inPlane: UInt8(i))
        {
            characters = characters + String(c)
        }
    }
    print("characters not in set: \'\(characters)\'")
}
 }


 enum HMACAlgorithm {
case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

func toCCHmacAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
    var result: Int = 0
    switch self {
    case .MD5:
        result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
    case .SHA1:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
    case .SHA224:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
    case .SHA256:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
    case .SHA384:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
    case .SHA512:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
    }
    return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
}

func digestLength() -> Int {
    var result: CInt = 0
    switch self {
    case .MD5:
        result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA1:
        result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA224:
        result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA256:
        result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA384:
        result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .SHA512:
        result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
    }
    return Int(result)
}
 }
 extension String {
func hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
    let cKey = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let cData = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    var result = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(algorithm.digestLength()))
    CCHmac(algorithm.toCCHmacAlgorithm(), cKey!, strlen(cKey!), cData!, strlen(cData!), &result)
    let hmacData:NSData = NSData(bytes: result, length: (Int(algorithm.digestLength())))
    let hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength76Characters)// Encoding76CharacterLineLength)
    return String(hmacBase64)
}

var urlEncoded: String {
    let customAllowedSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._~")
    return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: customAllowedSet)!
}

var urlQueryEncoded: String? {
    return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
}

func substring(to offset: String.IndexDistance) -> String {
    let to = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
    return String(self[..<to])
}
 }

 extension Dictionary {

var urlEncodedQuery: String {
    var parts = [String]()

    for (key, value) in self {
        let keyString = "\(key)".urlEncoded
        let valueString = "\(value)".urlEncoded
        let query = "\(keyString)=\(valueString)"
        parts.append(query)
    }

    return parts.joined(separator: "&")
}
 }

 extension Date {
func toMillis() -> Int64! {
    return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
}
 }
 extension StringProtocol {
var containsLetters: Bool { contains { $0.isLetter } }
 }


 public extension CharacterSet {

static let urlQueryParameterAllowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.subtracting(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "&?"))

static let urlQueryDenied           = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed.inverted()
static let urlQueryKeyValueDenied   = CharacterSet.urlQueryParameterAllowed.inverted()
static let urlPathDenied            = CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.inverted()
static let urlFragmentDenied        = CharacterSet.urlFragmentAllowed.inverted()
static let urlHostDenied            = CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed.inverted()

static let urlDenied                = CharacterSet.urlQueryDenied
    .union(.urlQueryKeyValueDenied)
    .union(.urlPathDenied)
    .union(.urlFragmentDenied)
    .union(.urlHostDenied)


func inverted() -> CharacterSet {
    var copy = self
    copy.invert()
    return copy
}
 }



 public extension String {
func urlEncoded(denying deniedCharacters: CharacterSet = .urlDenied) -> String? {
    return addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: deniedCharacters.inverted())
}
 }
```

Comment: Check out SO questions in other languages for OAuth and NetSuite. Ex. Delphi : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957730/ Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957730/  PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867476/

Comment: Please check the code.

Comment: `let base_url =  "baseurl"`needs the real base url (without parameters).

Comment: Base URL is updated.  Changed here for posting. But is is correct in xcode. Still getting the same response as
{"error" : {"code" : "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT", "message" : "Invalid login attempt."}}

Comment: Have you done a test call in Postman or similar tool to make sure it is signing related and not a permissions issue?

Comment: TIME_STAMP should be the number of seconds since midnight at the start of January 1, 1970 in UTC. Milliseconds is wrong.

Comment: Yeah I tested in Java as well as in Postman, I am getting the expected result. Checking the Time_Stamp.

Answer (score 0):

See one confirmed error so far.

```
var TIME_STAMP = String(Date().toMillis())
```

The time stamp needs to be seconds since 1970 and not milliseconds. The Java code you reference retrieves milliseconds and divides it by 1000 to get seconds.

```
String TIME_STAMP = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
```

You are not generating the HMAC off the baseString and Key in the code below.

```
func computeSignature(baseString: String, keyString: String) -> String
{
    let hmacResult:String = keyString.hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm.SHA1, key: keyString)
    return hmacResult
}
```

Comment: Even after sending TIme stamp in seconds its same error.

Comment: You are rolling too much of your own code - there should be easily accessible and tested code to URI encode a string, generate a HMAC etc.