# Integration Laravel with Netsuite

Tags: laravel, netsuite, oauth-1.0a

is there someone who has experience in implementing Netsuite account with Laravel. 
I need implement OAuth 1.0 RESTlet authorization header.
Thanks .

Comment: It’s going to be all about the headers. I did a SOAP integration. I can try RESTLets.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32983952/3230114