# Netsuite Rest Web Services Signature

Tags: rest, netsuite

I am working on an integration with Netsuite Rest Web Services API (not SOAP/RESTlets).
I have it fully functioning in postman using the supplied collection but have not figured out the actual string for the signature and the REST documentation doesn't show anything. I have attempted to use the documentation from both of the other services and no go.

So, pulled the log from postman I have tried to replicate what I believe it to be doing in using the account id, consumer key, token, creating a nonce, and unix timestamp.

> GET /rest/platform/v1/metadata-catalog/record?select=customer HTTP/1.1
>   Accept: application/swagger+json Authorization: OAuth
>   realm="TSTDRV2164811",
>   oauth_consumer_key="2bb1d46bb5f3a69fdea1ede39bf46e186bd860a15d8deaf51f7488b1e09bd2a2",
>   oauth_token="02545230f53d0cf8fc5075f8cee01847f28131127fad358501479952bb8ce046",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1579805526",
>   oauth_nonce="V5GBSPyMRPB", oauth_version="1.0",
>   oauth_signature="rp6xmqnCofmVPl9D0nk48G9DVww%3D" User-Agent:
>   PostmanRuntime/7.22.0 Cache-Control: no-cache Postman-Token:
>   cbc0f225-374c-4ecc-8b5b-daf60469137e Host:
>   tstdrv2164811.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com Accept-Encoding: gzip,
>   deflate, br Cookie: NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING Connection: keep-alive

```
<?php

$url = 'https://TSTDRV2164811.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/rest/platform/v1/metadata-catalog/record?select=customer';
//$url = 'https://rest.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=6&deploy=1&customParam=someValue&testParam=someOtherValue';
//or https://webservices.netsuite.com/services/NetSuitePort_2015_2 for webservices
$httpMethod = 'GET';
$tokenKey = '02545230f53d0cf8fc5075f8cee01847f28131127fad358501479952bb8ce046';
$tokenSecret = '8c4bb18a6ff15a699825ad833845d0a3dc3abca80aa89abe3c58f77eecd96f9e';
$consumerKey = '2bb1d46bb5f3a69fdea1ede39bf46e186bd860a15d8deaf51f7488b1e09bd2a2';
$consumerSecret = 'a684af8065f75f647ff24f58c3eeb48423907981ea7b93027f53cf63dcfd7626';
$signatureMethod = 'HMAC-SHA1';     //or HMAC-SHA256
$version = '1.0';
$nonce = 'V5GBSPyMRPB';                  //substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 10);
$timestamp = '1579805526';              //  time();
$realm = 'TSTDRV2164811';                   //scompid


$baseString = 'oauth_consumer_key='. $consumerKey;
$baseString .= '&oauth_nonce='. $nonce;
$baseString .= '&oauth_signature_method='. $signatureMethod;
$baseString .= '&oauth_timestamp='. $timestamp;
$baseString .= '&oauth_token='. $tokenKey;
$baseString .= '&oauth_version='. $version;
//$baseString .= '&realm='. $realm;

$base = urlencode($baseString);
$sign = $httpMethod .'&'. urlencode($url) .'&'. $base;
$key = urlencode($consumerSecret) .'&'. urlencode($tokenSecret);

$signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $sign, $key, true)));

$output .= sprintf(
    '<root><signature>%s</signature><Nonce>%s</Nonce><Created>%s</Created></root>',
    $signature,
    $nonce,
    $timestamp
);



echo $output;
```

I would expect to get the above value but instead I get this

```
<root>
    <signature><![CDATA[MW0rGmPfcY7yxLOMSWV6jcWs6s8%3D]]></signature>
    <Nonce><![CDATA[V5GBSPyMRPB]]></Nonce>
    <Created><![CDATA[1579805526]]></Created>
</root>
```

I modified my previous code to what i currently am trying and still no go

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867476/oauth-implementation-in-netsuite-using-php you are pretty far off on building the string to sign.

Comment: I believe that is for the RESTlets connection for calling scripts as it includes script ID and deploy ID, neither of which I am using. I am able to call netsuite and the error logs to confirm that nonce, timestamp, etc are all correct, just need the sign now

Unfortunately, netsuite support is limited to getting it working properly in postman. Since it is working, they are done and its on me now. I was able to find the postman repository (https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-runtime/blob/develop/lib/authorizer/oauth1.js). My js is weak at best so trying to figure out the base string still.

Comment: Think of the string to sign as one big URL with parameters in alphabetical order and URI encoded with the operation put in front (POST, GET etc). For example the timestamp portion before URI encoding would be: `&oauth_timestamp=1580228539` and after `%26oauth_timestamp%3D1580228539`  Also note the Realm parameter is not included in the text to sign (NetSuite Account) as per the OAuth standard.

Comment: I hope if those are real TBA credentials you have already revoked them!

Comment: Yes, I already revoked them.

Answer (score 0):

The string that you generate a signature for has to be constructed in a very specific way.

Operation in all caps + `&` + URI encoded Base URL + `&` + URI encoded block of parameters in alphabetical order excluding `realm`. It also needs to include some OAuth parameters in addition to any in the web request itself like `oauth_signature_method`.

Here is an example in a different language of constructing the string to sign.

```
  // These are in alphabetical order, lower case - required by signing
  STRING2SIGN := '';
  STRING2SIGN := STRING2SIGN + 'deploy=' + SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_ID + '&';
  STRING2SIGN := STRING2SIGN + 'oauth_consumer_key=' + CONSUMER_KEY + '&';
  STRING2SIGN := STRING2SIGN + 'oauth_nonce=' + OAUTH_NONCE + '&';
  STRING2SIGN := STRING2SIGN + 'oauth_signature_method=' + 'HMAC-SHA1' + '&';
  STRING2SIGN := STRING2SIGN + 'oauth_timestamp=' + TIME_STAMP + '&';
  STRING2SIGN := STRING2SIGN + 'oauth_token=' + TOKEN_ID + '&';
  STRING2SIGN := STRING2SIGN + 'oauth_version=' + OAUTH_VERSION + '&';
  STRING2SIGN := STRING2SIGN + 'script=' + SCRIPT_ID;
  STRING2SIGN := URIEncode(STRING2SIGN);
  STRING2SIGN := HTTP_METHOD + '&' + URIEncode(BASE_URL) + '&' + STRING2SIGN;
  oauth_signature := URIEncode(TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(THashSHA1.GetHMACAsBytes(STRING2SIGN, CONSUMER_SECRET + '&' + TOKEN_SECRET)));
```

Can leave out request parameters not in your request like `deploy` and `script` but need to include all the `oauth_` ones and any additional ones that are included in your request.

Comment: so i modified the code above to what i believe matches and still no go. My test values dont match what i pulled from postman logs and if i attempt a live connection im getting an invalid signature error still. clearly im missing something still but no idea what at this point

Comment: @BrentTobiczyk A quick look: `$signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $sign, $key)));` needs a true parameter added to hash_hmac so it outputs raw bytes instead of lower case hex. So `hash_hmac('sha1', $sign, $key, true)`

Comment: same. still invalid signature in netsuite and doesn't match the tested values.

At this point I have to assume they are expecting something non-standard. If I could get the test values to match at least then I would know it is creating the signature correctly (for what they are looking for). I just cannot get the signature to match.

Comment: Another difference: `$key = urlencode($consumerSecret) .'&'. urlencode($tokenSecret);` should be `$key = $consumerSecret .'&'. $tokenSecret;`

Comment: yeah. that was leftover from trying things. i tried with and without the urlencode.

Answer (score 0):

There is something strange about how PostMan stitches variables together to build up the URL. If you paste in the URL, rather than the {{REST_SERVICES}} that is built up from the {{COMPANY_URL}}, you get a different signature for the same exact nonce and timestamp values. So you really can't compare what PostMan is doing vs your own code.