# NetSuite OAuth 1.0 signature REST Api

Tags: typescript, oauth, netsuite, access-token

I have read through the docs and every post, on Stack Overflow, I could find on creating a signature for NetSuite OAuth1.0 with TBA. From what I can see I am inputting all of the requirements and correctly creating the key however when I make the call to the server I am still getting

"Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"

I have done the following:

- made a successful connection through postman
- disabled cors policy in chrome and am making calls there
- I have tried every possible combination I can as far as the parameters added to the base string.

I can confirm I have been unable to replicate the signature from postman (using the same parameter values) however I did read a post that, that does not necessarily indicate I am wrong since postman uses some other PM specific parameters/variables (not sure how valid that is.)

I have followed the documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_157652390285.html
as well as all of the related docs.

the following post is the closest to answering the questions however NetSuite no longer supports HMAC-SHA1, but other than me changing to HMAC-SHA256 I am providing all of the same parameters.(and then some per the docs.)

similar question with answer that I believe I am matching minus some additions from NS docs: [Netsuite Rest Web Services Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59899921/netsuite-rest-web-services-signature)

One problem I am having is that all of the docs use PHP so I am trying to match that with the javascript equivalent. but I have never worked in php so I am no sure if I am using the wrong encoding methods or not.

```
        import axios from 'axios';
        import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
        import hmacSHA256 from 'crypto-js/hmac-sha256'
        import base64 from 'crypto-js/enc-base64'

        function encodeRFC3986URIComponent(str: string) {
            return encodeURIComponent(str)
                .replace(
                    /[!'()*]/g,
                    (c) => `%${c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()}`
                );
        }

        const parameters = {
            grant_type: "client_credentials",
            oauth_consumer_key: consumerKey,              
            oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA256",
            oauth_timestamp: timeStamp,
            oauth_token: accessToken,
            oauth_nonce: nonce,
            oauth_version: "1.0",
        };

        const signatureKey = encodeURIComponent(consumerSecret) + '&' + encodeURIComponent(tokenSecret)
        console.log('signatureKey: ', signatureKey)

        var baseString = httpMethod + '&' + requestURL;

        for (const key in parameters) {
            baseString += "&" + key + "=" + parameters[key as keyof object];
        }

        const encodedBaseString = encodeRFC3986URIComponent(baseString)

        const signature = base64.stringify(hmacSHA256(encodedBaseString, signatureKey));

        let data = JSON.stringify({
            "q": "SELECT id, entityid FROM employee WHERE custentity_time_badge = '12345'"
        });

        let authorizationHeader = 'OAuth realm=' + OauthRealm

        for (const key in parameters) {
            authorizationHeader += ',' + key + "=" + parameters[key as keyof object];
        }
        authorizationHeader += ',oauth_signature=' + signature
        authorizationHeader = JSON.stringify(authorizationHeader)

        let config = {
            method: 'post',
            maxBodyLength: Infinity,
            url: 'https://5283244-sb2.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql',
            headers: {
                'prefer': 'transient',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': authorizationHeader,
                'Cookie': 'NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING'
            },
            data: data
        };

        axios.request(config)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the Cookie header?

Comment: @Krypton I just removed and the "Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie" is gone from the console however I am still getting a 401 response from the server. would this only be due to sending mis-hashed Oauth data, or is it possibly another issue?

Comment: Well, a different error is progress of some sort, at least :).  "401" means "Unauthorized" so it seems to be something awry in the Oauth data, as you say.  I only know enough about oauth in NetSuite to know that it can be frustrating to get started, but one thing from your code struck me as strange: why do you `JSON.stringify()` the auth header?

Comment: @Krypton, honestly, I was throwing darts at the wall to see if something would stick. I removed that and now I am getting a 400 code so yet another step in the right direction. One thing I will mention is that my signature ends with an "=" and both the NS docs for rest signature example and the PM end with an encoded %3D however there's nothing in the docs about encoding the end product. I have tried it and it does not seem to make a difference still 400 response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Krypton for getting me pointed in the right direction.
after he helped me isolate the problem to truly being the wrong credentials,
I went to the following doc and started from scratch to create a signature that matched the signature in the doc.

Doc: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1534941088.html

After I worked out the issues that were causing the signature to be incorrect I had a working example.

and now my code is as follows

```
        const parameters = {
            oauth_consumer_key: consumerKey,
            oauth_nonce: nonce,
            oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA256",
            oauth_timestamp: timeStamp,
            oauth_token: tokenKey,
            oauth_version: "1.0",
        };

        let e_baseString = httpMethod + '&' + encodeURIComponent(requestURL) + '&'
        let firstiteration = 0
        for (const key in parameters) {
            if (firstiteration === 0) {
                e_baseString += key + "%3D" + parameters[key as keyof object];
                firstiteration = 1
            } else {
                e_baseString += "%26" + key + "%3D" + parameters[key as keyof object];
            }
        }
        
        const e_key = encodeURIComponent(consumerSecret) + '&' + encodeURIComponent(tokenSecret)
        let signature = base64.stringify(hmacSHA256(e_baseString, e_key))
        signature = encodeURIComponent(signature)

        let authorizationHeader = 'OAuth realm="' + OauthRealm + '"'
        for (const key in parameters) {
            authorizationHeader += ',' + key + '="' + parameters[key as keyof object] + '"';
        }
        authorizationHeader += ',oauth_signature="' + signature + '"' 

        console.log('authorizationHeader: ', authorizationHeader)

        let data = JSON.stringify({
            "q": "SELECT id, entityid FROM employee WHERE custentity_time_badge = '123456'"
        });

        let config = {
            method: 'post',
            maxBodyLength: Infinity,
            url: 'https://5283244-sb2.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql',
            headers: {
                'prefer': 'transient',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': authorizationHeader,
            },
            data: data
        };

        axios.request(config)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Once again, Thanks Krypton I am working with multiple new frameworks/libraries ect. you helping me to isolate the problem was a huge help.

Comment: Good to see you got it working.  I was just coming here to comment on the ordering of the parameters and the "grant-type" which I didn't see in the docs: were there any other issues?

Comment: Yes, the grant-type was a) a misunderstood requirement on my part and b) I did not even think about the fact that it was out of order as you are pointing out. Also, the encoding function I was using was not required I was trying to match php's rawurlencode but regardless encodeURIComponent suffices. I also needed to encode the signature to match the NS docs. I also failed to encode part of my base string, which is now hard-coded to match NS.