# NetSuite Signature Creation

Tags: rest, oauth, netsuite, signature

I am successful with this in PostMan and trying to reverse engineer how the signature is created.  I have been successful with "tutorials" but not with this, I've tried everything I can think of, different variations of the URL, different sequence of encoding, etc...  I am still not successful.  Any suggestions on what I can try or what I'm doing wrong are greatly appreciated.  Code Below:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import urllib.parse
import base64

client_secret = '3d1cxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
token_secret = '9axxxxxxxxx'

accept = 'application/swagger+json'
oauth_consumer_key='f1415068f6b2ab480d1f'
oauth_token =   'b0dc6b9449'
oauth_nonce = '8ADKswXgwCa'
oauth_timestamp = '1581522490'
oauth_signature_method ='HMAC-SHA256'
oauth_version = '1.0'
oauth_realm="ns_realm"
select = 'customer'

method = 'GET&'
url = 'https://ns_realm.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/rest/platform/v1/record'

basestring= ''
basestring = basestring + method
basestring = basestring + url
basestring = basestring + '&oauth_consumer_key='+ oauth_consumer_key
basestring = basestring + '&oauth_nonce='+ oauth_nonce
basestring = basestring + '&oauth_realm='+oauth_realm
basestring = basestring + '&oauth_signature_method='+oauth_signature_method
basestring = basestring + '&oauth_timestamp='+oauth_timestamp
basestring = basestring + '&oauth_token='+ oauth_token
basestring = basestring + '&oauth_version=' + oauth_version
basestring = basestring + '&select=' + select

basestring_encoded = urllib.parse.quote(basestring)

signature_key = client_secret+'&'+token_secret
signature_key = urllib.parse.quote(signature_key)

h = hmac.new(signature_key.encode('utf-8'), msg=basestring_encoded.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
h = base64.b64encode(h).decode()
```

Comment: I have a working PHP example here you could port https://stackoverflow.com/a/32983952/3230114

Comment: @michoel I think your example is where I started :)  I'll go back line by line and see what I'm missing.  Thanks!!

Comment: @michoel do you know if RESTlets authorize the same as the REST API that is currently in beta?

Comment: I would assume it's pretty similar but I haven't had a chance to try the REST API yet which anything other than postman