# Oauth implementation in netsuite using php and method GET

Tags: php, oauth, netsuite

This answer worked fine for me, but only with POST methods

[Oauth implementation in netsuite using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867476/oauth-implementation-in-netsuite-using-php/32983952#32983952)

I'm trying to use the same technique, but with GET method and get it working, here is my code

```
<?php
//date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

define("NETSUITE_URL", 'https://5240409-sb1.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl');
define("NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_ACCOUNT", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID", 'XXXXXX');
define("NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET", 'XXXXXX');

define("NETSUITE_CLIENT", 'XXXXXX');

function sendOrderToNS($details) {
    $oauth_nonce = md5(mt_rand());
    $oauth_timestamp = time();

    $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    $oauth_version = "1.0";

    $base_string =
        "GET&" . urlencode(NETSUITE_URL) . "&" .
        urlencode(
            "deploy=" . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID
          . "&oauth_consumer_key=" . NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY
          . "&oauth_nonce=" . $oauth_nonce
          . "&oauth_signature_method=" . $oauth_signature_method
          . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $oauth_timestamp
          . "&oauth_token=" . NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID
          . "&oauth_version=" . $oauth_version
          . "&script=" . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID
          . "&client=" . NETSUITE_CLIENT
        );
    $sig_string = urlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET) . '&' . urlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET);
    $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $base_string, $sig_string, true));

    $auth_header = "OAuth "
        . 'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($signature) . '",'
        . 'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($oauth_version) . '",'
        . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($oauth_nonce) . '",'
        . 'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($oauth_signature_method) . '",'
        . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY) . '",'
        . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID) . '",'  
        . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp) . '",'
        . 'realm="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_ACCOUNT) .'"';

        var_dump($auth_header);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, NETSUITE_URL . '?&script=' . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID . '&deploy=' . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID . '&client=' . NETSUITE_CLIENT);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'Authorization: ' . $auth_header,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ]);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump($result);

    curl_close($ch);
}

sendOrderToNS();
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
"{"error" : {"code" : "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT", "message" : "Invalid login attempt."}}"
```

I'm pretty sure this error is for a malformed signature, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: And what's wrong?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Sorry for that, I'll edit the question and add the error message that I'm receiving

Comment: Hey man, have you sort this? I am having the same problem! So complicated to generate that shitty authentication header

Comment: @EzequielFernandez yes, the problem was with the order of the parameters, it needs to be in an alphabetical order

Comment: For anyone finding this in 2021.. need to use 

$oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256';

and hash_hmac("sha256"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the query params, it needs to be in a alphabetical order, so instead of

```
$base_string =
        "GET&" . urlencode(NETSUITE_URL) . "&" .
        urlencode(
            "deploy=" . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID
          . "&oauth_consumer_key=" . NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY
          . "&oauth_nonce=" . $oauth_nonce
          . "&oauth_signature_method=" . $oauth_signature_method
          . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $oauth_timestamp
          . "&oauth_token=" . NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID
          . "&oauth_version=" . $oauth_version
          . "&script=" . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID
          . "&client=" . NETSUITE_CLIENT
        );
```

I had to do

```
$base_string =
        "GET&" . urlencode(NETSUITE_URL) . "&" .
        urlencode(
            "client=" . NETSUITE_CLIENT
          . "&deploy=" . NETSUITE_DEPLOY_ID
          . "&oauth_consumer_key=" . NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY
          . "&oauth_nonce=" . $oauth_nonce
          . "&oauth_signature_method=" . $oauth_signature_method
          . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $oauth_timestamp
          . "&oauth_token=" . NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID
          . "&oauth_version=" . $oauth_version
          . "&script=" . NETSUITE_SCRIPT_ID
        );
```

Comment: Nice man, thanks! I got that but what if you need to send a POST or PATCH with body parameters? it works for GET but not for others

Comment: I have a post example here too, just changed the GET to POST and added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, "POST"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);`

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5OQQ10 expires in 24hours, try to save

Comment: Thank you very much for that, it was very helpful! But still does not work fine. Sometimes you need to send a GET for example with ?paramaeteres and it does not work with that.. like=  /customer?expandSubResources=true or /salesOrder?q=otherRefNum+is+{$otherRefNum}  , etc.. I have spent already 5 days and I am so frustrated.  I cant believe that Oracle doing this kind of shit

Comment: The most secure authentication, eather who is authorized cant authenticate lol, @EzequielFernandez are you putting those parameters in alphabetical order? and adding the url with those paremeters to the `restlet_url`?