# Laravel NetSuite Oauth1 issue

Tags: php, laravel, netsuite

Please help me to solve the issue. I am trying to connect with NetSuite API using Laravel Http client. But everytime I am getting an Error. I have tried many ways to connect with the Apis but everytime I am getting this in response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT",
        "message": "Invalid login attempt."
    }
}
```

Here is my Laravel code:

```
    $stack = HandlerStack::create();

    $middleware = new Oauth1([
        'consumer_key'    => '****************',
        'consumer_secret' => '****************',
        'token'           => '****************',
        'token_secret'    => '****************',

    ]);
    $stack->push($middleware);



    $client = new Client([
        'handler' => $stack
    ]);

    $response = $client->get('https://25365236.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=222&deploy=1&email=myemail@gmail.com.net&password=Pass@123');
```

Another code example:

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization'         =>  'OAuth realm="****",oauth_consumer_key="********",oauth_token="*******",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1615613004",oauth_nonce="****",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="C12wcF9Jowiw9vjxW5q4bHd/wxNoU+y+Ai2JeiOUBp4="',
            'Content-Type'  =>  'application/json',
            'User-Agent-x'  =>  'SuiteScript-Call',
        ])->get('https://11111.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=846&deploy=1&email=myemail@gmail.com.net&password=Pass@123');
        return $response;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oauth implementation in netsuite using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867476/oauth-implementation-in-netsuite-using-php)

Comment: I'm using ryanwinchester/netsuite-php for NetSuite and It works very well. You have all classes from NetSuite there too. It's easiest way to build requests after that.