Netsuite Oauth implementation with PHP - Invalid login attempt
I tried to implement the OAuth authorization for the NetSuite APIs with PHP, and I keep getting invalid login attempt.
I already reread my code again and again, but I really cannot see what's wrong here.
Here is my code:
public function call_api($end_point, $method, $data = false) {
        $timestamp = time();
        $nonce = uniqid(mt_rand(1, 1000));

        $curl = curl_init();

        $url = "https://5735036-sb1.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer";

        switch ($method) {
            case 'POST':
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

                if ($data) {
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
                }

                break;
            default:
                if ($data) {
                    $url = sprintf('%s?%s', $url, http_build_query($data));
                }
        }

        $parameters = array(
            'limit' => '100',
            'oauth_consumer_key' => $this->consumer_key,
            'oauth_nonce' => $nonce,
            'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA256',
            'oauth_timestamp' => $timestamp,
            'oauth_token' => $this->access_token_id,
            'oauth_version' => '1.0',
            'offset' => '100',
            'sort' => 'start:asc'
        );

        $signature_base_string = $method . "&" . rawurlencode($url) . "&" . rawurlencode(http_build_query($parameters, '', '&'));

        $signature_key = rawurlencode($this->consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($this->access_token_secret);
        $oauthSig = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $signature_base_string, $signature_key, true)));

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: OAuth ' .
                'realm="5735036_SB1", ' .
                'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode($this->consumer_key) . '", ' .
                'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode($this->access_token_id) . '", ' .
                'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256", ' .
                'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($timestamp) . '", ' .
                'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($nonce) . '", ' .
                'oauth_version="1.0", ' .
                'oauth_signature="' . rawurlencode($oauthSig) . '"'
        );

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $body = substr($result, $header_size);

        curl_close($curl);

        $body = json_decode($body);

        return $body;
}

Here is the error:
object(stdClass)#12 (4) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(58) "https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-15.5.2"
  ["title"]=>
  string(12) "Unauthorized"
  ["status"]=>
  int(401)
  ["o:errorDetails"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#13 (2) {
      ["detail"]=>
      string(152) "Invalid login attempt. For more details, see the Login Audit Trail in the NetSuite UI at Setup > Users/Roles > User Management > View Login Audit Trail."
      ["o:errorCode"]=>
      string(13) "INVALID_LOGIN"
    }
  }
}

All my credentials are obviously correct (it works well through Postman).
Any insights on what might be wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Did you already check for more details, in the place the error message told you to?

Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867476/oauth-implementation-in-netsuite-using-php
